# Identify 3D Tic Tac Toe type of game

Tags: identify-this-game, tic-tac-toe

Looking for the name and rules of the game.

Four identical pieces. Each a clear plastic double cube with a red round bead in the center of one cube (half of the piece) and a green round bead in the center of the other cube (half). Players take turns placing each of their two pieces. Subsequent moves are made by repositioning a piece already played (following certain rules). Play is contained in a virtual 3x3x3 cube. Win with three in a row horizontal, vertical, diagonal, and/or 3D.

The game might be from 70s or 80s - not sure. Please help. I have the pieces but that's it. And pieces (pun intended) of memory.

Comment: Could you include a picture of the pieces you have?

Comment: Any chance the game is [Cube Fusion](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/615/cube-fusion)? There are several versions, but the descriptions of the components match yours. 

Here's the [double-cube component](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/216859/cube-fusion) with a green and red bead in each respective half. 

Let me know if this is it and I'll make it a formal answer.

Comment: @Manath Good Job! That is exactly as described. Specifically MINI Cube Fusion must be the version OP has with only 4 pieces (double-cubes) total.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Cube Fusion](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/615/cube-fusion), specifically the [MINI Cube Fusion](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1113991/cube-fusion?size=original) version as Jay A pointed out based on the number of components.

From the description:

> The game includes a playing board with a 3x3 grid and 12 playing
>   pieces. **Each piece consists of two cubes, each with marbles in the
>   center - one red, one green.** Players take turns placing pieces on the
>   board, trying to make a specified pattern in his color but not his
>   opponent's -- all the while having to play both his color and his
>   opponent's color each turn. There are several different games
>   explained in the rules: make 3, 4, or 5 in a row (in 3D) before your
>   opponent, form a square in your color, form more three-in-a-row
>   alignments than your opponent, etc.